# Symmetrization map over the polynomial ring of a vector space.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, graded-modules, symmetric-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex vector space. Is the morphism
\begin{gather*}
\mathrm{Sym}^{\bullet}(V \oplus V^*) \to D(V) \cong \frac{\mathrm{T}^{\bullet}(V\oplus V^*)}{I} \,, \\[0.5em]
(v_1, w_1) \cdots (v_n, w_n) \mapsto \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{\sigma\in S_n}(v_{\sigma(1)}, w_{\sigma(1)}) \otimes \cdots\otimes (v_{\sigma(n)}, w_{\sigma(n)}) \bmod I \,,
\end{gather*}
where $I := \langle [x,y] = y(x) : x \in V, y \in V^* \rangle$, a morphism of $\mathbb{C}[V]$-modules? Clearly, it is a linear map over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I don't see a $\mathbb{C}[V]$-module structure on the RHS at all...

Comment: You are right. I apologise for my sloppiness. I meant the algebra of differential operators D(V) on the RHS. It has a natural $\mathbb C[V]$-module structure. I corrected my question.

Comment: Which one? Left multiplication or right multiplication?

Comment: I think the left multiplication is the right one here.

Comment: I don't understand $I$

Comment: @reuns, I corrected the ideal $I$. Replace $1$ by $y(x)$. The relation in $I$ comes from the relations in the Weyl algebra of a symplectic vector space.

Comment: Still unclear what is $I$ and $[x,y]$, how it shall be a two-sided ideal of $T$

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look to me to be true even if $V$ is $1$-dimensional. In this case the algebra of differential operators $D(V)$ is the Weyl algebra $k[x, \partial]/([\partial, x] = 1)$ while the LHS is the polynomial algebra $k[x, y]$ in two variables, and the symmetrization map, if I have understood correctly, sends

$$x \mapsto x, y \mapsto \partial$$
$$xy \mapsto \frac{x \partial + \partial x}{2}$$

which shows that it does not respect either the left multiplication $k[x]$-module structure or the right multiplication $k[x]$-module structure on the Weyl algebra (not surprising since it "mixes" the two through symmetrization).

Comment: I agree with you about the map. However, if we assign elements of $V$ degree $1$ and elements in $V^*$ degree $0$,  the PBW-isomorphism of $\mathbb C$-vector spaces $\mathbb C[V]\otimes_{\mathbb C}\mathbb C[V^*]\to D(V)$ implies an isomorphism of finite free $\mathbb C[V]$-modules  $F_iD(V)\cong \mathbb C[V]\otimes_{\mathbb C}F_i\mathbb C[V^*]$. Taking the colimit then yields $D(V)\cong \mathbb C[V]\otimes_{\mathbb C}\mathbb C[V^*]$ as $\mathbb C[V]$-modules. Am I right or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: @Flavius: such an isomorphism exists but it isn't given by symmetrization, it is just the multiplication map $\mathbb{C}[V] \otimes \mathbb{C}[V^{\ast}] \to D(V)$ where elements of $\mathbb{C}[V]$ are interpreted as multiplication operators and elements of $\mathbb{C}[V^{\ast}]$ are interpreted as differentiation operators. E.g. in the $1$-dimensional case this isomorphism sends $x^i y^j$ to $x^i \partial^j$.

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan: Let me sum up. The $\mathbb C$-linear isomorphism $\mathbb C[V]\otimes_{\mathbb C}\mathbb C[V^*]\cong D(V)$ ís in fact given by the symmetrisation map, defined in my question, but the $\mathbb C[V]$-linear isomorphism  $\mathbb C[V]\otimes_{\mathbb C}\mathbb C[V^*]\cong D(V)$ is given by the multiplication map, as explained in your comment. Do you agree with these statements?

Comment: @Flavius: I don't know what you mean by "the" in either of those expressions. Symmetrization is a $\mathbb{C}$-linear isomorphism and the multiplication map is a $\mathbb{C}[V]$-linear isomorphism.

Comment: @ Qiaochu: Sorry about that. I meant that the symmetrization map $\mathbb C[V]\otimes_{\mathbb C} \mathbb C[V^*]\to D(V)$, as defined in my question, is a $\mathbb C$-linear isomorphism, whereas the multiplication map $\mathbb C[V]\otimes_{\mathbb C} \mathbb C[V^*]\to D(V)$, as defined in your post, is a $\mathbb C[V]$-linear isomorphism. I think that that is what you say in your last post, as well, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.